# Processing - how to load .txt file and draw 2d shapes?

Tags: processing

Im not sure about how to draw the shapes contained in a text file. 
i want to use loadStrings to load the data in text file and draw the corresponding 2d shapes.

Please help

the txt file is "data.txt" 
and the contents are:

```
ellipse 100,100,80,50
line 20,30,120,150
rect 0,100,50,70
```

Answer (score 1):

To draw shapes that are specified in a data file we can

- Choose a file format, csv will work nicely but we can also use a text file
- Decide what shape attributes to work with. For this example we will just use shape, x, y, width and height. We could also specify things like color and transparency.
- Write code that reads the file. Processing can read a text file with `loadStrings` If we use a csv format Processing will make things even easier.
- Write code that draws the shapes

In the first example we will format our data file like this:

```
ellipse,110,100,80,50
line,170,30,150,150
rect,10,100,50,70
ellipse,110,200,50,50
```

We could choose anything we like including white space to separate the elements. Here we went with comas. The file is saved as shape_data.txt in our sketch's folder.

The code:

```
// since we use position in our data to keep track of what each element is
// we name an index into each element
int shapeIndex = 0;
int xIndex = 1;
int yIndex = 2;
int widthIndex = 3;
int heightIndex = 4;

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  stroke(255);
  String [] shapeRows = loadStrings("shape_data.txt");
  for (String s : shapeRows){
    String [] elements = s.split(",");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(elements[xIndex]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(elements[yIndex]);
    int shapeWidth = Integer.parseInt(elements[widthIndex]);
    int shapeHeight = Integer.parseInt(elements[heightIndex]);
    String shape = elements[shapeIndex];
    if ("ellipse".equals(shape)){
      ellipse(x,y,shapeWidth,shapeHeight);
    } else if ("line".equals(shape)){
      line(x,y,shapeWidth,shapeHeight);
    } else if ("rect".equals(shape)){
      rect(x,y,shapeWidth,shapeHeight);
    }
  }
```

The next example uses a csv file instead of a plain text file. The data is still plain text and we still depend on the position of the elements but we get the advantage of the fact that elements are named and the names are stored in the file header.

The csv file will look like this and we will save it as `shape_data.csv` in the same folder as our sketch.

```
shape,x,y,width,height
ellipse,110,100,80,50
line,170,30,150,150
rect,10,100,50,70
ellipse,110,200,50,50
```

And the code:

```
Table table;

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
  table = loadTable("shape_data.csv", "header");
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  stroke(255);
  for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    int x = row.getInt("x");
    int y = row.getInt("y");
    int shapeWidth = row.getInt("width");
    int shapeHeight = row.getInt("height");
    String shape = row.getString("shape");
    if ("ellipse".equals(shape)){
      ellipse(x,y,shapeWidth,shapeHeight);
    } else if ("line".equals(shape)){
      line(x,y,shapeWidth,shapeHeight);
    } else if ("rect".equals(shape)){
      rect(x,y,shapeWidth,shapeHeight);
    }
  }
}
```

And when we run either sketch we will see this:
[image: Shapes drawn from a csv file]